# Abstract delegate call

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, abstract

So there is a way to call other contract using abstract prototype of that contract.
But what about delegate calls? 
I need to split my huge contract into separate pieces. 
So i can call my functions via delegate call (to make them able to change global state of main storage). 
The problem is that unlike the simple call (using abstract method), i have to call my own functions via such ugly way: 
`contract_address.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3("foo(uint,uint)")),bar1,bar2);`

Is there any way to perform abstract delegate call? Or maybe such plans to add this feature?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using libraries should be able to help somehow. The problem is that from a library function you cannot access the contract state.

```
library Helper {
  function add(uint x, uint y) internal constant returns (uint) {
    return x + y;
  }
}

contract C {
  function doSomething(uint x, uint y) public returns (uint) {
    return Helper.add(uint x, uint y);
  }
}
```